# Capturing vertical and horizontal scroll from mousewheel

Tags: delphi, winapi, mouseevent, delphi-xe2

I need to capture mousewheel events in my application to move the view area like modern UI's since my application will run mostly on laptops.

I have looked into Windows messages and apparently only controls inherited from `TWinControl` can recieve mousewheel messages.

I'm using `TApplicationEvents`, that can also capture those mesagges. I tried handling the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message, but it works only for vertical scrolling. I also tried handling `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_HSCROLLCLIPBOARD` messages, but they were not captured at all.

How can I capture both vertical and especially horizontal mousewheel messages and use them in my software?

Comment: What about handling [WM_MOUSEHWHEEL message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645614(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @LURD I am looking at that as well. Just wrapping up an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to respond to `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` messages. For instance, here's an extract from a class of mine which adds horizontal mouse wheel scrolling to a scroll box:

```
procedure TMyScrollBox.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg=WM_MOUSEHWHEEL then begin
    (* For some reason using a message handler for WM_MOUSEHWHEEL doesn't work.
       The messages don't always arrive. It seems to occur when both scroll bars 
       are active. Strangely, if we handle the message here, then the messages 
       all get through. Go figure! *)
    if TWMMouseWheel(Message).Keys=0 then begin
      HorzScrollBar.Position := HorzScrollBar.Position 
        + TWMMouseWheel(Message).WheelDelta;
      Message.Result := 0;
    end else begin
      Message.Result := 1;
    end;
  end else begin
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to handle the message **WM_MOUSEHWHEEL**.

Notice that the letter "H" is in there (**WM_MOUSE H WHEEL**).

I added a TApplicationEvent componenet and added the following code
to the OnMessage event:

```
uses VCL.Controls;

.....

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
  var ctrl: TWinControl;
begin
  ctrl := FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos); //first I need to find the control under the mouse

  if ctrl is T3DWorldViewerComponent then //then I need to make sure
                                          //that the control under the mouse
                                          //is the 3D World Viewer contains my graphics

    if msg.message = WM_MOUSEHWHEEL then //then I need to make sure that I want to scroll Horizontally
    begin
      if msg.wParam=4287102976 then //this indicates that I'm scrolling to the left
        world.CameraMoveTo(MyCamera.Position.X+0.03, MyCamera.Position.Y, MyCamera.Position.Z)
      else
      if msg.wParam=7864320 then //and this indicates that I'm scrolling to the right
        world.CameraMoveTo(MyCamera.Position.X-0.03, MyCamera.Position.Y, MyCamera.Position.Z);
  end;
end;
```

Done!

Comment: This isn't right. You certainly should not be calling `Mouse.CursorPos` and `FindVCLWindow` for each and every input event. That's a massive performance hit. Then, you should not be calling `Mouse.CursorPos` at all because it is asynchronous. You rather would use `GetMessagePos` to get the mouse position when the input event was generated. At the very least you need to test for `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` right at the start. It might be a lot easier just to add a handler for `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` to the control.

Comment: Alright. I'll have to change that in my software. Thanks for the info David.

Comment: But in this case you would not use GetMessagePos. The lParam value has the coords. And your interpretation of wParam is also badly awry.

Comment: yes, about the wParam I didnt know how else to interpret it. Do you have some info for me?

Comment: If you did it as a WndProc override as per my answer you could cast it as I show in my answer. That record allows you to break apart the params. Otherwise you can work it out from the docs. I think I gave a decent answer to your question already. I'm not sure what your answer is for. It has an awful lot of problems.

Comment: You really need to read the documentation for `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`. The 4287102976 is actually a -120 in the high-word, and 0 in the low-word. That's a rotation of `WHEEL_DELTA` to left. Neither the delta is guaranteed to be exactly 120, nor the user not pressing ctrl, shift etc.. Similarly 7864320 is +120 in the high-word. On another note, if you would test the message first, you wouldn't be calling various api functions for each and every queued message, but only for `WM_MOUSEHWEEL`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes your answer is great. My code works as is right now, it does what I need, and, well, it works. It might not be the correct way to do it, but it works and I just wanted to share what works for me. But your code is def looking better.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I did not understand the following: "On another note, if you would test the message first, you wouldn't be calling various api functions for each and every queued message, but only for WM_MOUSEHWEEL"... could you explain a little bit?

Comment: @xaid - If the message is not a WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, then you don't need to look for a control under the pointer. That's all I was saying.

Comment: Oooh ok now I understand, yes well that is logical

Comment: The code doesn't work. It's just that you haven't tested it enough to reveal the faults

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my code doesnt work? well I am using it and it does work.

Comment: That's because you haven't tested it enough as I said. It just appears to work. The documentation is clear. If you don't want advice why ask?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan don't get me wrong, I'm always interested in advices, but why claiming that my code doesn't work when it does work? I'm not saying it is the correct way to do what I asked for, but it does work. It might just not be the correct way to do it. It doesn't just appear to work, it actually works and my Camera in the 3D world does move left and right using my trackpad on my MacBook Air. So I guess it does work, it might just not be the most correct way to do it regarding the performance.

Comment: It works on your machine with your settings. On a different machine it could easily fail. Do you want us to help you or not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan oh you mean testing on different machine. Ofcourse I want help my friend thats why I asked the question here. I haven't yet tested the code you proposed but I will do so when I get the chance.